# How to fill a C++ container using a (lambda) function?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I want to initialize a container with pointers to objects. I currently have a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i < n;i++) {
    container.push_back(new Object());
}
```

Which C++ operation (i.e. similar to `std::transform`) is the right to replace this loop and initialize a container with `n` newly created objects?

Comment: Are you asking for `std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(container), n, /*my lambda*/)`?

Comment: Better to use smart pointers instead of raw owning pointers.

Comment: @Jarod42 To be fair, we don't know for sure that `container` doesn't contain smart pointers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux smart pointers with implicit constructors? Burn them all!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: a smart pointer accepting non explicit conversion... ouch (`emplace_back` might have been different, but then, it would leak if exception happens with container "resizing").

Comment: The API I am using gets raw pointers (and then takes ownership), so that's not my decision.

Comment: @allo API gets the pointers via the container created? If not, I'd drop it entirely and just pass the objects to API directly (then in a loop again...).

Comment: The API gets the pointers as single parameter, but I want to modify the objects later. The whole thing isn't something which needs to be optimized, but I wanted to learn a nice C++ idiom instead of a boring loop ;).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [std::generate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
constexpr int n = 10;
std::vector<Object*> v1(n);
std::generate(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [](){ return new Object(); });
```

or [std::generate_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

```
std::vector<Object*> v2;
v2.reserve(n); // pre-allocate sufficient memory to prevent re-allocations
               // (you should have done in original loop approach as well)
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v2), n, [] { return new Object(); });
```

Comment: I think a short example would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: Note that in order to "push back" elements, you need `std::back_inserter`

Comment: I think I will use ``std::generate`` as it is cheap to initialize the container with the right capacity before using it and then it does not need to be resized while filling it.

Comment: @allo: Even cheaper: `std::vector<O*> v; v.reserve(n); std::gen_n(...);` (reserve allocates a junk of memory, but doesn't initialise it - in contrast to `resize` or the constructor solution).

Comment: @allo It's not cheap; it'll construct the container with n default-constructed elements and then assign them later.

Comment: @songyuanyao Which is quite cheap for pointers ;). But I see, the reserve option seems to be even better.

Comment: @Ron You shold add `std::vector<O*>v;` to second approach to make clear that you need to start with *empty* vector (in contrast to first approach). Maybe add a hint to `reserve` as well?

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed. I even wonder if OP's use case could have been solved using a simple vector ctor overload: `std::vector<T*> v(n, new T());`?

Comment: @Ron`v(n, new T())` would have inserted the same pointer to all vector elements, which disqualified std::fill(_n) already...

Comment: @Ron I wouldn't... OP didn't want to pick generate_n because he feared effiency loss (see comments above), but together with reserve, the approach actually is even superior...

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) and [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) with lambda.

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(container), n, [] { return new Object(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal is this syntax:

```
std::vector<Object*> v1 = generate([](auto&&){ return new Object; }, 10).make_container();
```

where we say we want to generate 10 elements with a specific lambda, then we create a container of the asked for type.

It requires some boilerplate.  First, an input iterator that counts and calls a function:

```
template<class F>
struct generator_iterator {
  F f;
  std::size_t i = 0;

  using self=generator_iterator;
  friend bool operator==(self const& lhs, self const& rhs){ return lhs.i==rhs.i; }
  friend bool operator!=(self const& lhs, self const& rhs){ return lhs.i!=rhs.i; }
  using reference=std::result_of_t<F const&(std::size_t const&)>;
  using value_type=std::decay_t<reference>;
  using difference_type=std::ptrdiff_t;
  using pointer=value_type*;
  using iterator_category=std::input_iterator_tag;

  self& operator++(){++i; return *this;}
  self operator++(int){auto tmp=*this; ++*this; return tmp;}
  reference operator*()const{ return f(i); }
  pointer operator->()const { return std::addressof(f(i)); }

  friend difference_type operator-( self const& lhs, self const& rhs ) { return lhs.i-rhs.i; }
  self& operator-=( difference_type rhs )& {
    i-=rhs;
    return *this;
  }
  self& operator+=( difference_type rhs )& {
    i+=rhs;
    return *this;
  }
  friend difference_type operator+( self lhs, difference_type rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend difference_type operator-( self lhs, difference_type rhs ) {
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }

};
```

Next, a range primitive, with a `.make_container()` method that lets you convert ranges to containers either by passing the type explicitly or implicitly:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }

private:
  struct container_maker {
    range_t const* self;
    template<class C>
    operator C()&& {
      return {self->begin(), self->end()};
    }
  };
public:
  container_maker make_container()const{
    return {this};
  }
  // C is optional
  template<class C>
  C make_container()const{
    return make_container();
  }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It s, It f ) {
  return {std::move(s), std::move(f)};
}
```

We then glue these together:

```
template<class F>
auto generate( F&& f, std::size_t count ) {
  generator_iterator<std::decay_t<F>> e{f, count};
  generator_iterator<std::decay_t<F>> b{std::forward<F>(f)};
  return range( std::move(b), std::move(e) );
}
```

and this compiles:

```
std::vector<Object*> v1 = generate([](auto&&){ return new Object; }, 10).make_container();
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc956902d7505674).